# Alternately fill numpy array between non-zero values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a binary numpy array, mostly zero-valued, and I want to fill the gaps bewteen non-zero values with a given value, but in an alternate way.
For example:

```
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]
```

should result in either

```
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

or

```
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
```

The idea is: while scanning the array left to right, fill 0 values with 1 up the next 1, if you didn't do it up to the previous 1.
I can do this iteratively and in this way

```py
A = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0])
ones_index = np.where(A == 1)[0]
begins = ones_index[::2] # beginnings of filling section
ends = ones_index[1::2]  # ends of filling sections

from itertools import zip_longest

# fill those sections
for begin, end in zip_longest(begins, ends, fillvalue=len(A)):
    A[begin:end] = 1
```

but I'm looking for a more efficent solution, maybe with numpy broadcasting. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. How does `np.logical_xor.accumulate` exactly work?

Comment: @richardec If `xor` is a sum modulo 2, then `np.logical_xor.accumulate` is a *cumulative sum* modulo 2. So for instance, with `A` as given `np.logical_xor.accumulate` (when cast as an int) yields `[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]`, switching from 0 to 1 at every 1 in A that is encountered. The 'OR' operation fills in the 1's that were lost due to a switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One nice answer to this question is that we can produce the first result via `np.logical_xor.accumulate(arr) | arr` and the second via `~np.logical_xor.accumulate(arr) | arr`.  A quick demonstration:

```
A = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0])
print(np.logical_xor.accumulate(A) | A)
print(~np.logical_xor.accumulate(A) | A)
```

The resulting output:

```
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
np.where(arr.cumsum() % 2 == 1, 1, arr)
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
#        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: this is a code-only "answer", right?